# How to play a mp3 file in flask app with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask, mp3

## Python code

```py
from flask import Flask,render_template

mp3files=["/static/audio1.mp3","/static/ audio2.mp3"]

app=Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template("musicplayer.html", mp3files=mp3files)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

## Html code

```html
<div id="songlist">
   {% for filename in mp3files %}  
      <label class="songs" for="{{filename}}" >{{filenamme}}</label>
      <input id="{{filename}}" class="hide songs" type="radio" name="song" value="{{filename}}" onclick="fun()">
   {% endfor %}
</div>
```

```js
let songs = document.getElementsByClassName("songs");

function fun() {
    for (var i = 0; i < songs.length; i++) {
        if (songs[i].checked==true) {           
            let audio= new Audio (song[i]);
            audio.play();
            break;
            
        }
    }
```

audio is not playing. How can i solve this problem.

Error:

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (NOT FOUND)

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).